# Add all of the key values in a nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to write a function that add all of the the inner key and value pairs of a nested dictionary.

This is what I would pass in

```
Pets = {'family1':{'dogs':2,'cats':3,'fish':1},
       'family2':{'dogs':3,'cats':2}}
```

This is what I would expect as the result

```
{'dogs': 5, 'cats': 5, 'fish': 1}
```

This is the loop I have written so far

```
def addDict(d):
    d2 = {}
    for outKey, inKey in d.items():
        for inVal in inKey:
            print(inVal, " ", inKey[inVal])
            d2[inVal] = inKey[inVal]
    return d2
```

This prints

```
dogs   2
cats   3
fish   1
dogs   3
cats   2
```

and returns

```
{'dogs': 3, 'cats': 2, 'fish': 1}
```

But how can I get the data to be cumulative, because it is just giving me the data from the first dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
Pets={'family1': {'cats': 3, 'dogs': 2, 'fish': 1},
 'family2': {'cats': 2, 'dogs': 3}}
d={}
for i in Pets:
    for j in Pets[i]:
        if j in d:
            d[j] += Pets[i][j]
        else:
            d[j] = Pets[i][j]

print d

>> Output
{'cats': 5, 'dogs': 5, 'fish': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
pets = {'family1':{'dogs':2,'cats':3,'fish':1},
       'family2':{'dogs':3,'cats':2}}

def addDict(d):
    d2 = {}
    for outKey, inKey in d.items():
        for inKey, inVal in inKey.items():
            try:
                d2[inKey] += inVal
            except KeyError:
                d2[inKey] = inVal
    return d2

print(addDict(pets))
```

Output:

```
{'dogs': 5, 'cats': 5, 'fish': 1}
```

This is called as [EAFP principle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python). What you simply do, is try to add the value for a key. If the key is not present, it'll throw a `KeyError`. Catch that error and insert the key.

Answer (score 1):

You're so close! Just change the `=` in the part where you set d2's inval to `+=` and it should work. Basically, you want to add the value, not override it. But you also want to check if that key exists first before adding to it. So:

```
if inVal in d2: d2 [inVal] += inKey [inVal]
else: d2 [inVal] = inKey [inVal]
```

Comment: This would work if both the nested dictionaries had the same number of key-value pairs, else it would throw an error.

Comment: Ok, so simple `if` statement to check first. I'll add it in now

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do all the counting for you

```
from collections import Counter

def addDict(d):
    c = Counter()
    [c.update(a) for a in d.values()]
    return dict(c)

>>> Pets = {
            'family1':{'dogs':2,'cats':3,'fish':1},
            'family2':{'dogs':3,'cats':2}
            }
>>> addDict(Pets)
>>> {'cats': 5, 'fish': 1, 'dogs': 5}
```